# Make image to fit to the size of the Imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I have an Rounded Network ImageView. I'm facing problems in fitting the image inside the imageview. I have set the imageview height to 130*130. I have set a background placeholde image to the imageview. Now the problem is when i upload any profile image, the placeholder image will be visible. There is small circular blue color line inside the image. It's a placeholder image present at the back. How can I make it to fit into the imageview?.
Here is my code:

```
       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img_bg"
        android:padding="6dp" >

        <com.practice.project.RoundedNetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_img_default" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I used linearLayout to give a white background to the circular imageview.

The drwable used for white background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/70dp" />
</shape>
```

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: try       android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: I tried using fitXY. But it's not working

Comment: show code xml and java

Comment: why you set background placeholder ?

Comment: did u used setBackground or setResourceBg?

Comment: Yes. I used it in the java code. I used setDefaultImageResId() method in the java code. is it happening because of that? If so what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: instead of android:background use android:src , try and let me know

Comment: I tried it.. Even it gives the same result

Comment: I tried it again..now the placeholder image is not visible. But it's not center aligned. I mean it takes more padding on top & left, then on right & bottom

Comment: Yes. But it's not aligned properly. I gave same padding for all 4 side. But still, it takes more space on top. Why this is happening?

Comment: u r setting   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"...plz make it center only

Comment: Even after making  android:layout_gravity="center", it's not working

Answer (score 0):

In my project it looks like this and it works:

```
            <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_ship"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/show_Button"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp" />
```

Hope it will help in some way...